# Why does the declarative notation return strings when integers are passed?

Tags: magento2, javascript

This in a template file:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {

            "component": {
                "my_config" : "<?php echo 0; ?>"
            }

        }
    }
</script>
```

will be transformed to a string in the component javascript file. This is really annoying because 0 is not a falsey value in js, so:

```
if(config.my_config){ ... }
```

will not work. This is just an example, there are others where you want to make sure you return integers and you lose time trying to debug what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code produce:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {

            "component": {
                "my_config" : "0"
            }

        }
    }
</script>
```

But looks like you need:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {

            "component": {
                "my_config" : 0
            }

        }
    }
</script>
```

So write code like:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {

            "component": {
                "my_config" : <?php echo json_encode(0); ?>
            }

        }
    }
</script>
```